# How do I access a header file/find its location?

Tags: c, header, libraries, file-location

I'm running through some source code that I was given, but I'm accessing it through SSH. It includes a header file or two which i'm not familiar with and I don't believe is part of the C libraries that are provided.

Is there a way that I can do this? Where should I look in the system files to see what this header file contains?

The top of the file reads:

```
23  #include <stdio.h>
24  #include <stdlib.h>
25  #include "support.h"
```

But there is no support.h file in the .c file's directory...where could it be?

Comment: Depends on the platform you're connected to by SSH. If it's Linux, you can check /usr/include, usr/local/include as a good start.

Comment: You might just have to search for it in the OS with a simple file search.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `find <project-root-dir> -name support.h`. It's likely to be in a directory like `include`, but of course could be anything. Also if it builds, you can look at the compile command and see what `-I` directories are supplied. As a last resort you can try `locate support.h` or `find / -name support.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart form searching the filesystem with either `find` or `locate`, if you have access to the makefile, you should find the information in the compilation line after in a `-I` argument.